# How To - render a string as a template in django

Tags: django-views

i've been wondering about how  i could render a template just by passing a made-inside-view string so that i woudn't have the need to create an html file. I read the Django Docs, but i couldn't find an explanation on this, as far as seen all was about giving the template path string, (also i tried a few lines, but got nothing).

Please, have this as an example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def my_view(request):
    arbitrary_string_as_template = """
        <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit">
            submit
        </button>
        </form>
    """
    return render(request, arbitrary_string_as_template, {})
```

So if this can be done... then i think it would have in its way a good potential, since it gains in terms of versatility..and btw..

#I'm New to Django

**Thanks for your attention**

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a [**`Template`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template) with the template string, and then [**`.render(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template.render) it:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template, RequestContext

def my_view(request):
    arbitrary_string_as_template = """
        <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit">
            submit
        </button>
        </form>
    """
    template = Template(arbitrary_string_as_template)
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

If however the content is static, I would advise to use a file. It makes it easier to *separate concerns*, and write clean files that each focus on a specific part.

Comment: Many thanks!! this helps a lot, and in case i want to add more context i would just need to update the dictionary with the other one.

Comment: @ArturoBolívarLabautdelRío: you can pass a context with `context = RequestContext(request, {'name': value})`, so add a dictionary as second parameter to `RequestContext`.